# If $a$ is prime to $M=\prod p_i^{n_i}$ and $ a^M \equiv a \ (\text{mod} \ M)$ then $\ a^{p_i} \equiv a \ (\text{mod} \ p_i^{n_i})$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Show that if $a$ is prime to $M=\prod p_i^{n_i}$ (for primes $p_i$) and $ a^M \equiv a \ (\text{mod} \ M)$, and a belongs to the exponent $e_i$ modulo $p_i$, then:
$$\frac M {p_i^{n_i}} \equiv 1 \ (\text{mod} \ e_i), \ a^{p_i} \equiv a \ (\text{mod} \ p_i^{n_i})$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a^{M-1}=1\bmod p_i^{n_i}$ and $a^{(p_i-1)p_i^{n_i-1}}=1\bmod p_i^{n_i}$ gives that

$$a^{g_i} = 1\bmod p_i^{n_i}$$ where $$g_i=\gcd(M-1,(p_i-1)p_i^{n_i-1}) = \gcd(M-1,p_i-1)$$

Comment: Why can we say that $a^{M-1}=1\bmod p_i^{n_i}$ ? It's probably obvious, but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: This is implied by $a^{M-1}=1\bmod M$

Comment: Being modulo 1 for a product of coprime factors implies it's modulo 1 for each factor?

Comment: $M$ divides $a^{M-1}-1$ so $p_i^{n_i}$ divides $a^{M-1}-1$